# Merge multiple application context files dynamically

Tags: spring, xslt, maven, xml-parsing, maven-3

I'm building a web application which uses Maven and is composed by a main system and many module *wars*, each one is an *Spring-3* based project with his own **ApplicationContext.xml file**. System and modules are *war* files and I use Maven to merge them using layouts.

At the beginning, **only the system *application context* file is loaded** and the system itself loads the *application context* of each module which is stored in `WEB-INF/classes/application_context` folder with different names.

This is how system is loaded:

```java
ServletContext context = SessionUtils.getServletContext();
ApplicationContext appContext = WebApplicationContextUtils
            .getRequiredWebApplicationContext(context);
```

And this is how the system performs the work of loading the rest of the *application contexts*:

```java
String filename = "/WEB-INF/classes/application_context";
ServletContext servContext = SessionUtils.getServletContext();
String pathname = servContext.getRealPath(filename);
File dir = new File(pathname);
List<String> contexts = new ArrayList<String>();
for (File child : dir.listFiles()) {
    contexts.add("/application_context/" + child.getName());
}
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
    contexts.toArray(new String[contexts.size()]));
```

My question is, is there a way to load every Spring Context at once? As I see there is a chance to do an [Spring import](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?66611-Import-Spring-Config-files), but initially system's *application context* doesn't know anything about the module ones. Also Maven can be used [to merge every application context in an only one](http://mojo.codehaus.org/xml-maven-plugin/), but I don't know how to use it exactly in that case, should I write an xslt file? I want some straight forwarded way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wildcards can be used when specifying context paths. For example:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:conf/*-Context.xml");
```

Take a look at section: [5.7.2 Wildcards in application context constructor resource paths](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch05s07.html).

You can also use a wilcard in your main context, so when server context is loaded, everything contained in that wilcard will be also loaded. That's how you can achieve a full load when server starts.

`<import resource="classpath:application_context/ApplicationContext*.xml" />`

Comment: Good point. However, I want to avoid loading modules application context by code. I want to do everything at once.

Comment: I added some code into the question explaining how I load the system itself. Can I load the rest of them at this time?

Comment: Edited according to my necessities.

Comment: I don't know if I understand completely, but once the application context is being loaded, I think the system will know modules deployed with it, no? Perhaps you already have solved it :)

Comment: Gotta solved @Nazar Annagurban. The challenge was doing it at once when the server loads ;-)